# JMeter connect to queue IBM MQ webshare error JMSWMQ2013

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq

I try to connect to queue by `JMeter` and IBM MQ Webshere like on the photo. I did .bindings file, ContextFactory, QueueConnectionFactory and `MQQueueConnectionFactory`. I did it like here : http://shekup.blogspot.se/2009/06/oc4j-mq-series-adaptor-with-mdb-30-as.html

in JMeter I have : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2A29.jpg)

And I don't know why I have error :

> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The
>   security authentication was not valid that was supplied for
>   QueueManager 'MYQM' with connection mode 'Client' and host name
>   '(1500)'. Please check if the supplied username and password are
>   correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.

Comment: Just a guess, but is the username and/or password you are supplying correct?  Is there a way for you to verify by logging in to a known working system?

Comment: When I add login and password is this same.